# Using standard input as input when debugging with Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, input, pipe

I've been trying to use a redirected text file as input for debugging my project. However I cannot get Visual Studio to actually execute any of the commands I have in the text file.

I've attempted to read up on a few other Stack Overflow questions but cannot figure out how to actually get the commands to execute.

And of course I attempted to read the MSDN documentation, however the closest I could get to was this:

[image]

The following is also a sample of my command inputs:

```
add Gregory Whitfield,U-61306479,arcu.Sed.eu@eu.net,4,3,5
add Brandon Hoffman,U-48162864,quis@Nullasemper.co.uk,1,0,5
add Gabriel Horne,U-49358227,cubilia@interdum.co.uk,3,2,0
add Emmanuel Wilson,U-25720188,mi.fringilla.mi@nonenimMauris.org,6,1,0
add Wing Paul,U-05895915,nec@odiotristiquepharetra.net,4,3,2
add Dustin Nielsen,U-77163005,eu@odioNaminterdum.com,2,2,2
add Timon Hooper,U-23370163,tristique.aliquet@sedpede.ca,6,2,3
add Uriah Silva,U-31580761,non.enim.Mauris@Nulla.net,1,2,5
add Abbot Austin,U-87255621,ac@nullaante.co.uk,4,0,0
add Sylvester George,U-57782586,nibh.Donec.est@Seddiamlorem.net,-1,0,1
```

`add` being a command of the program I want to test.

And finally, the debugging properties I currently have (however I've tried a lot of different command arguments):

[image: Command Arguments here]

Could someone tell me what I need to input for the command arguments to actually get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

You're using a relative file name. If you look at a trace of [Process Monitor (SysInternals)](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) with a filter like

```
Path contains TestData.txt then Include
```

you'll see that Visual Studio tries to load the file from the project directory.

[image: Process Monitor]

Possible solutions:

- move `TestData.txt` to the root of the project
- specify a full path (maybe using variables)
- specify a relative path like `Debug\TestData.txt`